# SQLite database connection string

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I have very big database (.db) file on my system **(>20 GB)** 
which holds aprrox **500 tables** and some tables have **billion records.**

This database I am going to use by C# program.

I have prepared queries which going to execute over these database and fetch records.
I also written INDEXING queries to execute over this database.

Below is the First step which making connection to the Database.

```
 string fullPath = "D:\\Example.db"

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + fullPath + ";Version=3;Count Changes=off;Journal Mode=off;Pooling=true;Cache Size=10000;Page Size=4096;Synchronous=off"))
            {
                con.Open(); 
                ....
                ....
}
```

- Can I still able to increase the Cache size ?
- Can I still increase Page size ?
- Shall I missing any other parameters ?

I am executing queries in loop so Can I able to **release CACHE** size through some commands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do understand that it's limitation to use big volume of database with SQLLite, so I have migrated my database with Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cache size at any time with [PRAGMA cache_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size).
However, this will not have much of an effect because the operating system will use any free memory to keep the databse file in the file cache.

The page size must be set before the database file is actually created.
Increasing the page size might help, but the effect is likely to be very small with such a large database where the runtime is dominated by I/O.

When you write queries that need to read gigabytes of data from the database, these queries will always be slow.